# nested json array parsing

Tags: c#, json

I am having a difficult time parsing a json response with C# asp.net. mostly with the array within array structure of this response. I have edited the post to reflect the json object. I think we can omit the deserialzation code.

```
{"Level1":
 [
 { 
   A:"some",
   B:"more",
   C:"stuff"
 }
 ],"DataLevel":
 [[
     { "AnotherLevel":
        { 
          "File":"data" 
        }, 
       "More":"stuff"
     }
  ]]} 

  // C# code
  public class JsonObject
  {
      public Level1[] level1 {get;set;}
      public DataLevel[] datalevel {get;set;}
  }
  public class Level1
  {
      public string A {get;set;}
      public string B {get;set;}
      public string C {get;set;}
  }
  public class DataLevel
  { 
      // ??
      // Seems like this should be public AnotherLevel anotherlevel {get;set;}
      public string More {get;set;}
  }
```

Comment: Please include your source code, not just the json you want parsed.

Comment: yup, np just edited it  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so looking at your data I would say your class definitions do not match the json you posted. Look closely at it. You have an object with 2 properties. One is an array of objects, the other is an array of object arrays. Below I have a different set of class definitions that should solve your problems.

```
public class OuterObject
{
     public FirstArrayObject[];
     public List<ObjInNestedArray[]>;
}

public class FirstArrayObject
{
   public string A;
   public string B;
   public string C;
}

public class ObjInNestedArray
{
     string property1;
     AnotherLevel AnotherLevel;

}

public class AnotherLevelObj
{
      string prop1;
}

OuterObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterObject>(responseBodyAsString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good this is and didn't check if it is actually correct but you could try this website http://json2csharp.com/, but it might help you in some way!

This is the result I got when I used the json data you provided:

```
class Level1
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Level1> Level1 { get; set; }
    public List<List<>> DataLevel { get; set; }
}
```